# Most Lite-Weight XML Parser with XPath and Wide-char Support

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, unicode, xpath

I want a lite-weight C++ XML parser/DOM that:

1. Can take UTF-8 as input, and parse into UTF-16.  Maybe it does this directly (ideal!), or perhaps it provides a hook for the conversion (such as taking a custom stream object that does the conversion before parsing).
2. Offers some XPath support.

I've been looking at [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1dependencies_and_compatibility), the [Kranf xmlParser](http://www.applied-mathematics.net/tools/xmlParser.html), and [pugiXML](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/index.html). The first two of those *might* permit requirement #1 by way of a hook.  The third, pugiXML, supports the #2 requirement.  But none of those three fulfill both requirements.

What is the smallest (free) library that can handle both requirements?

Comment: I might take a C parser, if I can't get one that is Object-Oriented.

Comment: @Cristian Adam: post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pugixml has an [UNICODE branch](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/source/browse/#svn/branches/unicode). I guess UNICODE will be officially supported in the next version (0.6)

Comment: So far this seems to be just what was needed. :)

Comment: This library is very good indeed and now has a stable release which includes both XPath and UNICODE support :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd really go for [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) + [TinyXPath](http://tinyxpath.sourceforge.net/)... Tiny, fully UTF-8 compilant and zlib/MIT licensed. If you want a more C++'s like interface there's also [TinyXML++](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/)

Comment: From the TinyXML documentation: "TinyXML does not use or directly support wchar, TCHAR, or Microsoft's _UNICODE at this time".  So per requirement #1, it is immediately disqualified.